# How do I map set<DateTime> to List<Wrapper>?

Tags: apex, map

I have created a wrapper class for example:

```
List<wrapper> wrapperList = new List<wrapper>();
set<Id> ids1 = new set<Id>();
public class wrapper{
     String abc;
     String 123;
     Datetime latestDate;
}
```

I wrote a SOSL which is returned in the form of List

```
List<List<sObject>> results = [FIND :this IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING object1__c (Id, uniqueId, description)];
for(sobject obj : results){
    wrapper wrpr = new wrapper();
    wrpr.abc = obj.description;
    wrpr.123 = obj.uniqueId;
    wrapperList.add(wrpr);
    ids1.add(wrpr.123);
}
```

return wrapperList;

Now I have a soql query to fetch DateTime values.

```
List<object2> obj2 = new List<object2>();
    Datetime latestDate;
    set<Datetime> latestDateSet = new set<Datetime>();
    obj2 = [SELECT Id, UniqueId, (SELECT CreatedDate FROM Object3 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Object2 WHERE AND Id IN: ids1];
    for(Object3 obj3 : Object3){
        for(obj2 ca: obj3.obj2s){
            latestDate = ca.CreatedDate;
            System.debug('lastAttachedDate----'+lastAttachedDate);
        }      
        latestDateSet.add(latestDate);
    }
```

Note: uniqueId is the common Id value between SOSL and SOQL.

How do I add the DateTime values I fetched from the SOQL to the List returned from SOSL.

Comment: Thanks Phil for editing the code :)

Comment: P.S. you should [edit] your code to make it more legal. `123` is not a legal variable name. I get you're abstracting, but it should still *look* like legal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then `List<wrapper> wrapperList = new List<wrapper>();` try `Map<Id, wrapper> wrapperList = new Map<Id, wrapper>();`

### Notes:

I'm assuming UniqueId is a legit record Id based on how your query is written.

I'm also assuming that UniqueId is not a lookup field although I don't know why it wouldn't be if it is a legit record Id.

If any of these assumptions are wrong, this answer may not work for you.

This will allow you to easily find the correct wrapper based on the Id.

```
List<List<sObject>> results = [
    FIND :this 
    IN ALL FIELDS 
    RETURNING object1__c (
        Id, uniqueId, description
    )
];

for(List<sobject> objList : results){
    for (SObject obj : objList) {
        wrapper wrpr = new wrapper();
        wrpr.abc = obj.description;
        wrpr.uniqueId = obj.uniqueId;
        wrapperList.put(wrpr.uniqueId, wrpr); // Set the Id as the key
        // ids1.add(wrpr.uniqueId); this is no longer needed, see below
    }
}
```

Finally,

```
obj2 = [
    SELECT Id, UniqueId, (
        SELECT CreatedDate 
        FROM Object3s
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
    ) FROM Object2 
    WHERE Id IN: wrapperList.keySet() // use keyset here
];

for(obj2 ca: obj2){
    List<Object3> obj3s = obj2.Object3s;

    if (obj3s != null && !obj3s.isEmpty()) {
        wrapperList.get(obj2.Id).latestDate = obj3s[0].createdDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked just fine. Thanks gNerb :)